# '+' character converting into space in HttpParams angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript, encoding

Im having a JSON object and passing it using HttpParams but it coverts + to space and sent to backend. I have tried all possible ways but no one solved it for an JSONObject string.

```
this.updateUser({"name":"ABC","mobile": "+911234567890","text":"1 + 2 = 3"});

public updateUser(myObj) {

    const body = new HttpParams().set('user_object', JSON.stringify(myObj));
    return this.http.post(url, body, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8')
    });
  }
```

When I inspect in Network that object containing + character automatically converts into space.

Comment: try using quotation around your number. like "+911234567890" instead of +911234567890

Comment: Thats not an issue... In quotation also it won't work

Comment: Can't you use 'application/json' as content type?

Comment: Since im not handling json object at backend, Thats the reason of using `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: if you need to send 'x-www-form-urlencoded' then try use 'URLSearchParams' here + not converted to space... If you want more info then i will give you example..

Comment: wromg URLSearchParams converts + to space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ia a common problem. The `+` character is used by the URL to separate two words. In order to use the `+` character in the parameter values, you need to encode your parameter values before adding them as part of the URL. Javascript / TypeScript provide a `encodeURI()` function for that specific purpose.

> URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted
>   over the Internet. [**[w3Schools Reference]**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Here is how you can fix this problem:

```
let mobile = encodeURI("+911234567890");
let text = encodeURI("1 + 2 = 3");
this.updateUser({"name":"ABC","mobile": mobile,"text":text});

public updateUser(myObj) {
  const body = new HttpParams().set('user_object', JSON.stringify(myObj));
  return this.http.post(url, body, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8')
  });
}
```

OR

You can encode indside the updateUser() method:

```
this.updateUser({"name":"ABC","mobile": "+911234567890","text":"1 + 2 = 3"});

public updateUser(myObj) {
  let encodedJson = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(myObj));
  const body = new HttpParams().set('user_object', encodedJson);
  return this.http.post(url, body, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8')
  });
}
```

OR

Use a regular expression to replace `+` before sending to the server:

```
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(myObj);
jsonData = jsonData.replace(/\+/gi, '%2B');
```

Comment: What if I have a large json string??

Comment: then you can encode the entire json string as well. Check update.

Comment: It will encode whole json then and from backend I found error saying string not started with "{". Should I decode to my backend also?Or any other way we can handle on frontend side.

Comment: you get the error because now you have to decode the string in your backend!

Comment: Ok so no other option to handle on frontend?

Comment: You can use regular expression. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks @Faisal. Its worked now. Just to handle on backend with `%2B` in string.

Comment: Tihs would lead to double encoding and a need to manually decode once as well in the BE, this issue is related to following open bug; https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058. Instead of manually encoding, a better solution would be to override angular's default encoding here. which is something also suggested in the attached issue,

Answer (score 24):

This is a problem with HttpParams in angular. The `+` in a parameter value is converted to a . I had a similar problem wherein I had a POST request which accepts file in the form of Base64 encoded string. This Base64 conversion of the file can contain a `+` sign which was getting converted to a . I implemented a CustomURLEncoder in my project to handle the same. Following is the snippet for your reference:

```
import {HttpParameterCodec} from '@angular/common/http'

export class CustomURLEncoder implements HttpParameterCodec {
    encodeKey(key: string): string {
        return encodeURIComponent(key); 
    }
    encodeValue(key: string): string { 
        return encodeURIComponent(key); 
    }
    decodeKey(key: string): string { 
        return decodeURIComponent(key); 
     }
    decodeValue(key: string) {
        return decodeURIComponent(key); 
     }
}
```

And you can use the encoder with the HttpParams as follows:

```
import {CustomURLEncoder} from './urlencoder.component';
import {HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

export class ApiService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

    base64 = "Encoded+Base64+File+Data" //String with '+'
    const fileDetails = new HttpParams({encoder: new CustomURLEncoder() })
        .set('filename','CustomEncodedFile.xlsx')
        .set('filedata',base64);

    return this.httpClient.post(url, fileDetails, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www- 
        form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8')
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm using that top CustomURLEncoder as a service in my app but when i call ```encodeValue```its not working. Just returning my same string value.

Comment: Works like a charm. Tried many solutions but did not work except yours.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use formData Object to send request header data?

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("params",JSON.stringify(myObj));
```